# Making an image move across the x axis in Android?

Tags: android, imageview

I'm using this code to make an image (brickimg) move across the screen.

```
//This makes the brick move
   int x=brickimg.getRight()-brickimg.getLeft();
   int y=brickimg.getBottom()-brickimg.getTop();
   final TranslateAnimation translate = new TranslateAnimation(
           Animation.ABSOLUTE,x, Animation.ABSOLUTE,
           x, Animation.ABSOLUTE,y,
           Animation.ABSOLUTE,1000);//How far it goes
   translate.setDuration(450);//speed of the animation
   translate.setFillEnabled(true);
   translate.setFillAfter(true);
  brickimg.startAnimation(translate);
```

It only makes the image move across the y axis, but I'm trying to make it move across the x axis. I've changed a few of the variables around to see if that will change it, but it didn't. Does anyone know how to make it move across the x axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using same value for fromX and toX, so it's not moving on X axis, use this -

```
 final TranslateAnimation translate = new TranslateAnimation(
 Animation.ABSOLUTE,0, Animation.ABSOLUTE,
 x, Animation.ABSOLUTE,y,
 Animation.ABSOLUTE,1000);//How far it goes
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That works. One thing to note is that you have to make the second y value (1000) just y to make it work (.ABSOLUTE,y);